# How to get remove the 1st duplicate value of a 2D list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a 2D array as below in python:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.36, 20.0, 11.36, 20.02, 0.0], 
[13.38, 5.78, 19.94, 5.76, 19.96, 11.28, 13.4, 11.3], 
[6.72, 5.78, 13.28, 5.76, 13.3, 11.28, 6.74, 11.3],
[0.06, 5.78, 6.6, 5.76, 6.64, 11.28, 0.08, 11.3], 
[13.38, 0.16, 19.94, 0.14, 19.96, 5.66, 13.42, 5.68], 
[6.72, 0.16, 13.28, 0.14, 13.3, 5.64, 6.74, 5.68],
[0.04, 0.18, 6.62, 0.14, 6.64, 5.64, 0.08, 5.68],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.36, 20.0, 11.36, 20.02, 0.0]]
```

`[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.36, 20.0, 11.36, 20.02, 0.0]` is the duplicate array.
 I want to remove the 1st duplicate value and keep the last value.
So my output should be:

```
[[13.38, 5.78, 19.94, 5.76, 19.96, 11.28, 13.4, 11.3], 
[6.72, 5.78, 13.28, 5.76, 13.3, 11.28, 6.74, 11.3],
[0.06, 5.78, 6.6, 5.76, 6.64, 11.28, 0.08, 11.3], 
[13.38, 0.16, 19.94, 0.14, 19.96, 5.66, 13.42, 5.68], 
[6.72, 0.16, 13.28, 0.14, 13.3, 5.64, 6.74, 5.68],
[0.04, 0.18, 6.62, 0.14, 6.64, 5.64, 0.08, 5.68],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.36, 20.0, 11.36, 20.02, 0.0]]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use the pandas module:

```
import numpy as np
your_array=np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.36, 20.0, 11.36, 20.02, 0.0], 
[13.38, 5.78, 19.94, 5.76, 19.96, 11.28, 13.4, 11.3], 
[6.72, 5.78, 13.28, 5.76, 13.3, 11.28, 6.74, 11.3],
[0.06, 5.78, 6.6, 5.76, 6.64, 11.28, 0.08, 11.3], 
[13.38, 0.16, 19.94, 0.14, 19.96, 5.66, 13.42, 5.68], 
[6.72, 0.16, 13.28, 0.14, 13.3, 5.64, 6.74, 5.68],
[0.04, 0.18, 6.62, 0.14, 6.64, 5.64, 0.08, 5.68],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.36, 20.0, 11.36, 20.02, 0.0]])
```

to drop the duplicates use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(your_array)
df_without_duplicates = df.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```

If you'd prefer numpy array as output, use:

```
new_array = df_without_duplicates.values
```

Output:

```
array([[13.38,  5.78, 19.94,  5.76, 19.96, 11.28, 13.4 , 11.3 ],
   [ 6.72,  5.78, 13.28,  5.76, 13.3 , 11.28,  6.74, 11.3 ],
   [ 0.06,  5.78,  6.6 ,  5.76,  6.64, 11.28,  0.08, 11.3 ],
   [13.38,  0.16, 19.94,  0.14, 19.96,  5.66, 13.42,  5.68],
   [ 6.72,  0.16, 13.28,  0.14, 13.3 ,  5.64,  6.74,  5.68],
   [ 0.04,  0.18,  6.62,  0.14,  6.64,  5.64,  0.08,  5.68],
   [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 11.36, 20.  , 11.36, 20.02,  0.  ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: first you have to reverse the list to keep the last element, then a simple for loop will avoid repetition. Finally reverse again the list to have the desired output.

```
# l is your list

l.reverse()
res = []
for x in l:
    if x not in res:
        res.append(x)
res.reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be another solution. Iteratively drop the repeating lists.

```
x,y = 0,0
while x < len(l):
    y = x + 1
    while y < len(l):
        if l[y] == l[x]:
            l.pop(x)
            x = 0
            break
        y += 1
    else:
         x += 1
```